# VSCode auto filling "variable." to "variable={.}"

Tags: visual-studio-code, jsx, intellisense

While editing jsx/tsx files in VSCode, anytime I type a period after a variable name such as `variable.` it changes it to `variable={.}`

I have no idea why it is doing this. Does anyone know if an extension does this or if there is a way to see the history of activity done by extensions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While going through my 82 extensions I found out it was "JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly" by Microsoft. Hope this can help someone in the future.